# Error in writing ascii characters into a file in java/android

Tags: java, android, ascii, outputstream, filewriter

I have the following code:

```
private char[] headerToWrite;
protected String workingFileName;

private void writeHeaderToFile()
{
    try
    {
        String completeFile = new String(headerToWrite);

        File myFile = new File(workingFileName);

        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

        myOutWriter.append(completeFile);
        myOutWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) 
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the above code, the variable **headerToWrite** contains an array, where the first few values are: `[1, Q, H, S, , 4, ±, Q, .....]`. This in hex is `[31, 51, 48, 53, 01, 34, B1, 51...]`.

It is used to create a string **completeFile** which = 1QHS 4±Q...

However, when the file is being written, the file contains 1QHS 4Å±Q..... which in hex is `[31 51 48 53 01 34 c2 b1 51]`....

I couldn't understand why there was an additional c2 but I discovered that the bytes inside **myOutWriter** were as follows: `[49, 81, 72, 83, 1, 52, -62, -79, 81]`....

The interesting point here is the `-62, -79` which seems to be responsible for `c2, b1`. For it to work, `-62, -79` should just be `177`, which is the decimal for b1. Interestingly 177 + 79 is 256.

So evidently, in the transfer from ascii characters in **completeFile** to bytes in **myOutWriter**, `c2` is being added.

I was wondering if anyone could explain why and how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -79 can be explained by overflow. As `byte` is a signed char and 177 > 127 (which is the maximal value for a byte), it will overflow and -79 is the result. I can not really explain the -62, but you are clearly using the wrong encoding (probably UTF-8). Try using a different encoding ([ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) might do the trick).

Comment: Thanks that worked great. Just for completeness, I changed OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); to OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut, "ISO-8859-1");

Answer (score 2):

it could be because by appending a String, it actually converts it to byte array using default encoding, which is probably UTF-8. To fix this, convert your string into byte array by using ISO 8859-1 encoding and write that byte array to your output stream.